# How to get the youtube video thumbnail in java swing from the youtube api

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to display the **YouTube's video thumbnail** image for every video searched or featured. I just need the **syntax and method to implement** it in my java swing application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get the `SearchListResponse` from youtube v3 data api. Now you can easily fetch the thumb url using following code.

```
SearchListResponse response = // data fetched from yt data api.
java.util.List<SearchResult> searchResultList = response.getItems();
for (SearchResult sr : searchResultList) {
   String thumburl = sr.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getDefault().getUrl();
//for high resolution you can use:  sr.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getHigh().getUrl();
}
```

related links. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 3):

You can load the thumbnails directly via web request. Take a look at [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

***EDIT***

Here are some sample links:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<video-id>/default.jpg
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<video-id>/hqdefault.jpg
- or -
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<video-id>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18746587)

Comment: You are right. I just edited the answer and added some sample links. Thanks for the hint.